# How can i create a date and time picker as in the below image

Tags: android, calendar, datetimepicker

i need some lead on how i could develop time slot picker as show in the below screen shot.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evAAW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the opening times in some DB Table and fetch them via ajax, then you can use some js library like moment.js for getting "humanized" words from your times (eg. Morning, Afternoon, Evening etc.).

Apart from that its is just simple styling and ajax requests.

**Sample:**

```
var openingHours = getOpeningHoursFromDB();
var dayTime = "morning";    

function getGreetingTime (m) {
        var g = null; //return g

        if(!m || !m.isValid()) { return; } //if we can't find a valid or filled moment, we return.

        var split_afternoon = 12 //24hr time to split the afternoon
        var split_evening = 17 //24hr time to split the evening
        var currentHour = parseFloat(m);

        if(currentHour >= split_afternoon && currentHour <= split_evening) {
            g = "afternoon";
        } else if(currentHour >= split_evening) {
            g = "evening";
        } else {
            g = "morning";
        }

        return g;
    }

function buildTimepicker() {
   for(var openingHour in openingHours) {
     if(getGreetingTime(openingHour) != dayTime) {
       dayTime == getGreetingTime(openingHour);
       .....
       .....
     }
   }
}
```